# Ruby-1.9.3-p286 : can't install with RVM on OS X

Tags: ruby, makefile, rvm

TI'm trying to update Ruby on my system using RVM.
I currently use Ruby-1.9.3-p194 and everything works fine.

This is the command I use:

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3-p286
```

This is the output:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #configure
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #download
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #extract
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #validate
Libraries missing for ruby-1.9.3-p286: /opt/sm/pkg/versions/libffi/3.0.10/lib/libffi.5.dylib. Refer to your system manual for installing libraries
Mounting remote ruby failed, trying to compile.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/Tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p286, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p286 to /Users/Tom/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p286
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #extracted to /Users/Tom/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p286
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #configuring
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #compiling
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #installing 
Error running 'make install', please read /Users/Tom/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p286/install.log
There has been an error while running make install. Halting the installation.
```

The first warning on the missing libraries is annoying. Still, I could deal with compiling it from source... if only it worked.

This is the log:

```
$ cat /Users/Tom/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p286/install.log
[2012-10-21 19:41:13] make install
./miniruby -I./lib -I. -I.ext/common  ./tool/rbinstall.rb --make="make" --dest-dir="" --extout=".ext" --mflags="" --make-flags="" --data-mode=0644 --prog-mode=0755 --installed-list .installed.list --mantype="doc"
installing binary commands:   /Users/Tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin
installing base libraries:    /Users/Tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib
installing arch files:        /Users/Tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.2.0
installing pkgconfig data:    /Users/Tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/pkgconfig
installing command scripts:   /Users/Tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin
installing library scripts:   /Users/Tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1
installing common headers:    /Users/Tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/include/ruby-1.9.1
installing manpages:          /Users/Tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/share/man/man1
installing extension objects: /Users/Tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.2.0
installing extension objects: /Users/Tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.2.0
installing extension objects: /Users/Tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.2.0
installing extension headers: /Users/Tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.2.0
installing extension scripts: /Users/Tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1
installing extension scripts: /Users/Tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1
installing extension scripts: /Users/Tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1
installing extension headers: /Users/Tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby
installing default gems:      /Users/Tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1 (cache, doc, gems, specifications)
/Users/Tom/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/fileutils.rb:244:in `mkdir': File exists - /Users/Tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1 (Errno::EEXIST)
    from /Users/Tom/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/fileutils.rb:244:in `fu_mkdir'
    from /Users/Tom/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/fileutils.rb:221:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
    from /Users/Tom/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/fileutils.rb:219:in `reverse_each'
    from /Users/Tom/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/fileutils.rb:219:in `block in mkdir_p'
    from /Users/Tom/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/fileutils.rb:205:in `each'
    from /Users/Tom/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/fileutils.rb:205:in `mkdir_p'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:183:in `makedirs'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:284:in `prepare'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:539:in `block in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:597:in `call'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:597:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:594:in `each'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:594:in `block in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:590:in `each'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:590:in `<main>'
make: *** [do-install-nodoc] Error 1
```

I believe it says that a file it is trying to write already exists:

```
File exists - /Users/Tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1 (Errno::EEXIST)
```

I checked and this file appears to be a symlink to a file in a non existent directory:

```
$ ls -GFhl /Users/Tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
lrwxr-xr-x  1 Tom  staff    39B 17 Ott 13:29 /Users/Tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1@ -> /Users/mpapis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286
```

...It says `/Users/mpapis/`, who is one of the guys who authored RVM. Could it be a leftover of when he put together the installation script?

These japanese guys here seem to be able to install it: http://qiita.com/items/34e0ff2c369899169f90
... still, I'm lost.

Can anyone help, please? Is there a way to force the overwrite of that file?

Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue is fixed already https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1244 it's not yet available in `stable`, use `head`:

```
rvm get head
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```